# web3.toAscii is not a function

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js

I'm try to convert the `Bytes32` data to a string in Ethereum (Smart Contract), by using web3.toAscii. However, it throws me an error (web3.toAscii is not a function). Just wondering if this a known issue or a bug in web3 API?

Comment: You're trying to use web3 APIs in your contract?

Comment: @AdamKipnis - Pardon me for the mistake. I  tried in nodejs code with web3 API.

Comment: I've used `toAscii` without issue. Feel free to post your code according to the [SO guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get additional help.

Comment: Please provide some more details on your problem. Some part of your code perhaps. Without more description, we cannot  say what exactly to fix.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the beta version of web3 doesn't support `web3.toAscii`, just use `web3.utils.toAscii`

Comment: when you say new version. Are you referring to the beta web3 1.0.0?